Home network forwarding and NAT issue
I simply cannot understand what I'm missing, as NAT is something that I never fully understood.
I made a new "home network" and would like everyone to connect to a specific device listening on a specific port.
Users from outside network joins without problem, but other LAN users simply cannot.
I made simple but detailed diagram with pictures:
https://miro.com/app/board/uXjVKg2qVWI=/?share_link_id=564474834216
If anyone in spare time could explain as I was 5 what rules should I add to make it work.
I think I bought decent equipment and software is also capable of doing such basic things.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Can another device on the same subnet as the server (that is, on 192.168.3.x subnet, behind the "Network 1" ASUS router), reach the server successfully via the public IP address and port? I would guess it can. Can a device on LAN2, on the 192.168.7.x subnet (that is, on the LAN side of the EdgeRouter, but on the WAN side of the Network 2 ASUS router), reach the server successfully via the public IP address? I would guess that it cannot. I would guess that your EdgeRouter can't do Hairpin NAT between two of its own NAT instances; I bet it only does it within a single local NAT instance.

Does it work if the user connects to the L1 nat IP 192.168.6.39:25000, and bypasses the public nat situation? You may want to remove your public IP from the diagram

Thanks for replies. @Spiff yes you read the whiteboard right. As for Nat hairpin I have seen option to add additional interface. It's on screen too. Not sure if this is what we are looking for.

@Spiff yes you read the whiteboard right. As for Nat hairpin I have seen option to add additional interface. It's on screen too. Not sure if this is what we are looking for.

Also @Cpt.Whale you mean that other LAN users should join by LAN address and not public one? I will try that because I don't remember if I tried

@Aeit yes, try using the LAN IP in case of hairpin limitations with multiple NATs

@Cpt.Whale
Sadly, its not even an option. I have been told that everyone MUST use external IP.
It works for users under LAN where game server is hosted. Not for others.
When they type 192.168.6.39:25000 the status of applications shows offline

Also, when I disabled the checkbox for NAT hairpin in that PortForward, then users from the same network as the Server also cannot join. So apparently it works.
How to include other interfaces like eth1 (LAN2 users)
Anyone knows how to make proper NAT rules for this scenario?
This is how it works in EdgeRouter image

Are those other interfaces separate LANs/VLANs with their own subnets? If that's the case, hairpin shouldn't be the issue – hairpin is not a "both peers are internal" thing, it's more specifically "both peers are same subnet" thing.

The only solution was to change all routers to AP mode. Dual NAT is something that cannot be solved no matter what.
Then in Edgerouter I have added static IP routes between subnets, Hairpin NAT for LAN2

Yes it looks like EdgeRouter/EdgeOS devices require additional Hairpin NAT rules if your environment uses multiple LAN interfaces:
https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/204952134-EdgeRouter-Hairpin-NAT
You'll need to create a Source+Destination pair of NAT rules for each LAN interface.
